# Possible to modify / write to a custom parameters.yml file in symfony2?

Tags: php, oop, symfony

apologies for the possible n00b question but here we go. I'm currently writing a service class in symfony2 which collects data using ajax. The data basically consists of two timestamps sent upon form submit. What I then want to do is pass this to my controller and write it to a custom parameters.yml file so I can store the values in this file and update this file each time a user submits the form. I am getting an error like this :

```
Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag
```

And some searching on Google tells me that I cannot modify the Container once it has been compiled. The line in particular which is causing this is :

```
$this->container->setParameter('quicksign.start.off', $startOff);
```

Okay time to show my code. Here is my controller :

```
public function updateServiceSigAction() {

$logger = $this->get('logger');
$request = $this->get('request');
$errors = array();

if (WebserviceController::POST_ONLY && $request->getMethod() != 'POST') {
    $errors[] = "Not allowed !";
    return $this->sendResponse($errors);
}

$params = $request->request->all();

if (count($params) == 0) {
    $errors[] = "Missing parameters !";
    return $this->sendResponse($errors);
} else {

    $servicesig_services = $this->get('servicesigservice');
    $errors = $servicesig_services->updateServiceSig($params, false);

}

return $this->sendResponse($errors, array(), true);

}
```

And here is the relevant method of my service class :

```
public function updateServiceSig($params, $need_to_flush = true) {

$errors = array();

$startOff = $params['date_debut'];
$endOff = $params['date_fin'];

if (empty($startOff) || empty($endOff)) {
    $errors[] = "Missing parameters from query !";
} else {

    $this->container->setParameter('quicksign.start.off', $startOff);
    $this->container->setParameter('quicksign.end.off', $endOff);
}
return $errors;
}
```

Maybe I should do this before compiling the container ? But I don't know where exactly the container is being compiled...
Or maybe I should do it another way...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's how I got it done :

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Dumper; //I'm includng the yml dumper. Then :
$ymlDump = array( 'parameters' => array( 
   'quicksign.active' => 'On', 
   'quicksign.start.off' => $startOff, 
   'quicksign.end.off' => $endOff ), 
 );
$dumper = new Dumper(); 
$yaml = $dumper->dump($ymlDump);
$path = WEB_DIRECTORY . '/../app/config/parameters.sig.yml'; 
file_put_contents($path, $yaml);
```

Where WEB_DIRECTORY is defined in the app.php file -> however, you should use

```
%kernel.root_dir%
```

in the service configuration.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you are using the `parameters.yml` file wrong. [The official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html) states:

> One use for this is to inject the values into your services. This allows you to configure different versions of services between applications or multiple services based on the same class but configured differently within a single application.

So the file is **not for storing** a services state **but to configure the initial state**. You use it if multiple applications use the same source-code. An example would be a *staging* and a *production* environment, or multiple services in one application like two ORMs that need different connection parameters. With that said you should probably use an [entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) to store your timestamps in it.

If you *really* need a file you can use e.g. [Symfony's YAML component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/index.html) to manage a custom `.yml` file.

Comment: thanks for the reply. to answer you, it's actually a custom parameter file, not the default one, so I think it's okay to use in this way...

Comment: I also found a way of doing it, -> I added this to the service class :   `use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Dumper;` I'm includng the yml dumper. Then `$ymlDump = array(
         'parameters' => array(
          'quicksign.active' => 'On',
          'quicksign.start.off' => $startOff,
          'quicksign.end.off' => $endOff
         ),
        );$dumper = new Dumper();
   $yaml = $dumper->dump($ymlDump);$path = WEB_DIRECTORY . '/../app/config/parameters.sig.yml';
   file_put_contents($path, $yaml);`

Comment: If your solution solved your problem you should add it as an answer and accept it. I'm glad you got things working :)